# .NET System::Diagnostics::Process which uses a DLL C++

Tags: c++, .net

My current code looks something like this:

```
String^ callProcess(String^ cmd, String^ args)
{
    Process^ p = gcnew Process();
    p->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
    p->StartInfo->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p->StartInfo->CreateNoWindow = true;
    p->StartInfo->Arguments = args;
    p->StartInfo->FileName = cmd;
    p->Start();
    p->WaitForExit();
    String^ output = p->StandardOutput->ReadToEnd();
    p->Close();

    return output;
}
int main()
{
    String^ output1 = callProcess("handle.exe","-arg1");
    String^ output2 = callProcess("handle.exe","-arg2");
}
```

handle.exe opens a handle to a DLL let's call it HANDLE.DLL.  After trying to look at output2 it has something like "Error during SomeClass Call.... Can't get a handle to HANDLE.DLL".

It looks like the first call to CallProcess isn't properly releasing the handle to the DLL.  Is there a way I can force it to release the DLL handle?

Comment: I don't think your suspicions are correct. Multiple processes should be able to open a handle to the same DLL. The problem likely exists somewhere else, e.g. in the code for handle.exe

Comment: Even if I were to only execute CallProcess(...) once, while the Parent Process (a windows forms project) is running (GUI windows form app that doesn't close until you click [X] in top right corner), if I try to open a terminal on windows (cmd.exe") and run "handle -arg1" I will get the same error "Can't get handle to..."

Comment: If I close the parent process (the GUI app) then I can open a cmd.exe window and call the "handle.exe" process with no error thrown.

Comment: It looks like the "handle.exe" tool for the 1st call doesn't complete its run, is there any way to force that to happen?

Comment: **(1)** "Can't get a handle to Xxx.dll" is not a Windows error message that I recognize. I'm pretty sure it's *not* a Windows error message at all. So this has to be something generated by *your* code. **(2)** If `handle.exe` is not properly closing when it's finished, that's a problem with your code. You are not properly posting a quit message, processing the quit message, or any number of things. **Thus**, we cannot help you unless you post the important bits of the code for `handle.exe`.

Comment: Thanks Cody your suspicions are the same as mine.  Unfortunately I do not maintain nor have access to the handle.exe program, but as you mentioned it seems like it's not cleaning up it's resources properly.  The only thing that's strange is that if you run handle.exe in two separate cmd.exe windows, it will not throw this error, it's only when I try to call it through the .NET interface.